# How to make a correct redirection in django app after user delete his message in website?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a website watching a video course and sometimes I don't agree with mentor decisions about solving some tasks. And while i am trying to figure this out, the problem has already taken really much time and i haven't still found how to solve this.

At first I show the necessary source code.

1. **urls.py** and the the error url:

```
    path('delete-message/<str:pk>/', views.delete_message, name='delete-message')
```

2. **views.py** and function where error happens:

```
@login_required
def delete_message(request, pk):
    message = Message.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_id = message.room.id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message.delete()
        return redirect(f'room/{room_id}') ### WHAT DO I HAVE TO DO ???

    return render(request, 'delete-message.html')
```

3. **delete-message.html** and error form:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2>
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this message ?</p>
    </h2>
    <a href="{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}">Go Back</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

After `redirect()` works it sends me to the unexisted url: `127.0.0.1:8000/delete-message/10/room/5`but it had to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/room/5`...
**Why is it not as such result as I've expected?**

Also I've tried to do this:

1. In the views.py I change function where except of redirect I transfer room_id to the template:

```
@login_required
def delete_message(request, pk):
    message = Message.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_id = message.room.id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message.delete()

    return render(request, 'delete-message.html', {'id': room_id})
```

2. In the template **delete-message.html** I try to redirect back to the room by the "action" attribute:

```
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'room' id %}">
```

And this method also return an error:

```
IntegrityError at /room/5/
NOT NULL constraint failed: BaseApp_message.body
```

Comment: Share full urls.py file...

Comment: Use reverse to get a url using it's name. related: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: Add leading forward slash: `f'room/{room_id}'` → `f'/room/{room_id}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reverse` with url name space init like below :-

urls.py

```
path('room/<str:pk>/', views.room_message, name='room')
```

Then in your view will be :-

```
@login_required
def delete_message(request, pk):
    message = Message.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_id = message.room.id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message.delete()
        url = reverse('room', kwargs={'id': room_id})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a root-relative URL, add a leading forward slash:

```py
# return redirect(f'room/{room_id}')
return redirect(f'/room/{room_id}')
```

Comment: No, man, looks like it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a repro project on GitHub?